# Send mail to users

Tags: 7, users, emails

I'm looking for an simple module to send mail to the users of our site. It should be able to send a mail to all users of a certain roll, with the ability to put in a send from e-mail address. Just a simple form with send from, subject and body. Nothing fancy.

An optional extra would be that i can select users in a view and send them a mail using bulk operations.

I tried modules like simplenews and mass contact but they provide many things except a simple mail form.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Rules](http://drupal.org/project/rules) module to send email also. You can filter users from Role and send email to selected users.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the http://drupal.org/project/views_send module.It will gives you a lot of customization options even to set your own headers.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Views Bulk Operations in a view filterable by role. I believe Send email is a default action available.

Comment: yes but this uses the default site e-mail address